# Local variable assignment with command substitution behaves unexpectedly

Tags: bash

I got some troubles when managing dialog output and exit codes. Essentially I'm trying to get a one-line script for getting dialog selection and terminate script function:

```
local _ui_envname=$(dialog --stdout --cancel-label "Back" --inputbox 'Enter the new environment name:' 0 0) || { echo "Failed"; exit 1; }
```

However the above command fails miserably (the `{ echo "Failed"; exit 1; }` is not executed at all when `dialog` exit code is 1). The culprit seems to be the `local` keyword: removing the local variable specifier it starts working as expected.

What is going on? Am I doomed to use "global" variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not only `local`, all declaration utilities mask the exit code of the substituted command, because the assignment does not fail.

The usual workaround is:

```
local _ui_envname
_ui_envname=$(dialog --stdout --cancel-label "Back" --inputbox 'Enter the new environment name:' 0 0) || { echo "Failed"; exit 1; }
```